# Is it possibe to write Gnome extensions in Dart and compile it to JS?

Tags: dart, gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

In theory it looks like it should be possible. There is: [Dart-to-JavaScript compiler](https://dart.dev/tools/dart2js) and even [package to call JS from Dart and opposite](https://pub.dev/packages/js).

But I didn't find any resources about it. Did anybody tried? Does anybody knows for sure that it is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: maybe, but I seriously doubt it's worth the effort.

To do anything useful with JavaScript, you need to write for a platform like the [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API), [node.js](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/), or [GNOME](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org) in the case of GJS. Dart seems to support the Web API with its `web` library and its own platform with the `vm` library.

You might be able to write a transpiler that could transpose from a subset of Dart to GJS, but using any existing dart transpiler is probably impossible.